# insert trigger error #1064 sql person_info and Total_bank

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, mysql-error-1064

I want to make a query that will fill in data from other table into another.

```
INSERT INTO `Total_bank` VALUES (
 SELECT id,name FROM person_info WHERE name=
     (SELECT name FROM person_info WHERE personid=
      (SELECT MAX(personid) FROM person_info))
);
```

Its giving me the following error:

> #1064 on row 2

Table person_info:

[image]

Table Total_bank:

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to insert the row in `person_info` with the largest value of `personid`, then use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
INSERT INTO Total_bank (id, name)
     SELECT id, name
     FROM person_info
     ORDER BY personid DESC
     LIMTI 1;
```

Note that you should list the columns being inserted.

All that said.  The title to your question suggests that you are attempting to do this in a trigger.  **This is very dangerous code.**. I suspect there is a better way to do whatever you want.  You should ask a *new* question, provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.  The above does however answer the question that you have asked here.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the danger comes from the `SELECT MAX(autoincrementing_id) FROM table` pattern, which is almost sure to get race conditions and therefore errors, but only after you're done testing it and putting it into  production.

Comment: I have made a discord bot with php, and i already have data saved of each user so what i essentially want to do is link the discord id with the data that i got saved. And for this Total_bank i just want to make a insert that doesn't do much and it would only happen when a new discord id gets introduced into person_info.

Later i will have to make an update trigger to add up food to Tfood(Totalfood) for each data field. 

Thank you for the quick reply it works really well!